# Java JRE versions incompatibilty

Tags: java, applet, cross-browser

I have a question regarding the compatibility between different java versions.

On my computer, I have java version "1.7.0_02".
But when I uploaded the .class and embedded it in a webpage it does not work

I get the error:

"Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"

the heading at the top of the console says:
"Java Plug-in 1.6.0_31
Using JRE version 1.6.0_31-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM"

I would like to ask what is causing the problem. Is it really my java version?
I mean, I visited the site with the computer I compiled the applet in.

Comment: maybe your jdk version is not equal as your jre version?

Comment: The plugin in your browser is not the one corresponding to Java 1.7. Look for (and remove) JRE 1.6 in your computer.

Comment: You're building with java 7 and trying to run it on a JRE that only knows about java 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use classes compiled to Java 1.7-compatibility class files with an earlier virtual machine, and that "Java Plug-in" error you're seeing says that's exactly what happen.

Two options:

1. if you're not using Java 1.7 only features, you can compile your code to be compatible with 1.6 JVM's using the option -target 1.6 (see docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options))
2. Upgrade the Java plug-in your browser is using to 1.7, if possible (I don't think you can do this on OS X, for example).  You didn't note what OS and browser you're using so I'm not sure what the upgrade path would be, if any.

Comment: *"can compile your code to be compatible with 1.6"*  Or 1.1.  Ultimately, very few new classes, methods and attributes appropriate to an applet made by a newbie have been introduced over the years.  There are of course language constructs like 'for each' and Generics, but it is usually not hard to recode a small amount of source to not need them.  As an aside, I don't think there is a link to it in the index, but the most relevant part of that linked document is direct to the [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options)

Comment: Also, once you have decided the minimum version the code will run on, & compiled it with target, **source & bootclasspath** options, then use the `deployJava.js` mentioned in/linked from the [info. page on applets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) to ensure the end user has the minimum version needed to launch the applet, help them upgrade if not, then embed the applet.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I updated the link, thanks.  Good tip about deployJava.js, too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, I figured out what was wrong.

I started off with both 1.7 and 1.6 on my machine, and it was really confusing me.
The problem was, 1.7 was 64 bit, and 1.6 was 32 bit.

My browser was chrome 32 bit.

I just installed 1.7 32 bit and it was fine

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, it'd be nice if you accepted it!